# Merge entries in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

In my document, I am sometimes citing several papers at once, and none of them again afterwards, so to save space, I would like them to appear as one item in the bibliography. (The document I am compiling has a size limit)

So instead of this:

---

In the document, I cite [1][2][3]

Literature:

[1] some paper

[2] some other paper

[3] even another paper

---

I would like to have this:

---

In the document, I cite [1]

Literature:

[1] some paper, some other paper, even another paper

---

Is this possible at all? I can't find anything in the documentation about this.

Comment: You might be interested in using entry sets. (See page 128 of the `biblatex` documentation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to merge several different references and assign a single number to them, you can use entry sets as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key1,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key2,
  author = {Author, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key3,
  author = {Author, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@book{key4,
  author = {Author, D.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}

@set{set2,
  entryset={key3,key4},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\defbibentryset{set1}{key1,key2}
\cite{set1}
\cite{set2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Two different types of entry sets can be defined: static and dynamic entry sets. The former is defined in the `.bib` file using `@set` while the latter can be defined in the `.tex` file using `\defbibentryset`. The above MWE results in the following output.

[image]

If one wants to distinguish between individual entries of an entry set, one can use the `biblatex` option `subentry`. The above MWE with this option added yields the following output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, when attempting this (in a BibLaTex with BibTex backend context), the final bibliography shows the entries twice: I don't use subentry, but in the Bibliography I get fist the combined entry as your [1], and then in lines below (but still under the same number) also separate entries to A.Author's paper and B. Author's paper... any idea on this?. I tried working with collref before, but that was allso unsuccesful

Comment: I can confirm this. It seems as the above presented solution only works with `biber` rather than with `bibtex`. Could you switch to `biber`? If this is not an option for you, you could open a follow up question to this one.

Comment: Switching to biber gives me a whole bunch of warnings and no bibliography shown, perhaps I'll try again later